# separating lists by continuity of integers

Tags: python, list, math, tuples, signal-processing

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out a good way get the x indices associated with peaks from some xy dataset.
I know that d2y/dx2<0 and dy/dx=0 denotes a peak center at x. and inflection points are at d2y/dx2=0 and |dy/dx|>0.  But I would like to get the data from inflection to inflection as a list. (So a list of lists because I need to get several peaks)

So, I also am able to come up with this for the inflection point to inflection point list of values:

```
inflection_indices = [x for x in list( np.where( dY2dX2 < 0.0 )[0] )]
```

But, this just gives me one list of all of the peaks thrown together.

I would like to have a list of lists where each element of the overall list is a separate peak.

Like this:  [ 14,15,16,17,18,19,20, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 204, 205, 206, 207]

When i want this:  [  [ 14,15,16,17,18,19,20] , [89,90,91,92,93,94] , [204,205,206,207]  ]

Thank for any help with this, I would really appreciate it.

**EDIT:** I competely removed all of the tuples and such so I can add them in later, I think the question is more at the heart of the issue now.

Comment: I did not try it but perhaps `inflection_indices = [(x,) for x in list( np.where( dY2dX2 < 0.0 )[0] )]`. Note parenthesis and a comma

Comment: Not quite, that addition just puts each integer into its own tuple like so :  [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]

Comment: It would definitely help if you gave a sample to work with. I think you need few steps. Perhaps you can find breaks using np.diff(np.where( dY2dX2 < 0.0 )) and get indices where it is != 1 into some *a*. Then you would create start/end indices using a[:len(a)-1]-1 and a[2:] and create slices using those. Something along that line.

Comment: what does a[:len(a)-1] do? isn't that the same as a[-1] for one dimensional lists?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to this, but it's not very elegant at all...

```
self.list_of_peak_indeces = [x for x in list(np.where(self.dY2dX2 < 0.0)[0])]
temp_list = []
self.main_lists_of_peak_indices = []
difference_between_indices = np.hstack([np.diff(self.list_of_peak_indeces), np.diff(self.list_of_peak_indeces)[-1]+1])
    for index, item in enumerate(self.list_of_peak_indeces):
        if(np.absolute(difference_between_indices[index])!=1):
            if(temp_list!=[]):
                temp_list.append(item)
                self.main_lists_of_peak_indices.append(temp_list)
            temp_list = []
        else:
            temp_list.append(item)
```